# What happens to the fate point after a character invokes an aspect?

Tags: dresden-files, fate, aspects

In DFRPG, characters can invoke another character's aspects by spending fate points. When a character does this, does the fate point go to the GM, or does it go to the character whose aspect was just invoked?

Comment: Ok explain a little more
Do you mean compel another player or do you invoke another players.

do you have an example
Player 1 has aspect epic wiseass player 2 then says player 1's character is a wiseass so he would get in this fight first??

An example would help

Comment: @ax kidson if i understand correctly from the perspective of the person spending the fate point it's an invoke and from the person getting the point it's a compel.  To use your example player 1 pays a fate point to invoke player 2's aspect epic wiseass so that player 2 is compelled to play into that aspect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Was reading through and found this blurb on YS 106:

> The procedure to invoke an aspect that isn't on your character is
>   precisely the same as a regular invocation: just declare how that
>   aspect is relevant, spend a fate point, and take a +2 or a reroll.  The
>   only thing to keep in mind is that, if you're invoking an aspect on
>   another PC or on a NPC to gain an advantage over them, that character
>   will receive the fate point you spent, either at the end of the
>   exchange (in conflict, see page 197) or at the end of the scene
>   (outside of conflict).

Comment: I appreciate the citation, but could you unpack it a bit please? Particularly, does "invoking an aspect on another PC or on an NPC" mean any invoke on a roll against them, only aspects that are actually *on* the PC or NPC being opposed?

Comment: @besw I read it as any roll where you spend a fate point to use one of their aspects against them.  So let's say an npc has vanity as an aspect, and we're in a social conflict, i could throw a gnarly comment attacking his looks and invoke his vanity aspect with a fate point.  i would get the +2 and he would get the fate point.

Comment: But what about if I invoke a `Tough Crowd` aspect that's on the location, instead? Does he get the point even though the aspect is on him, or does the point evaporate?

Comment: @besw since that's the envronment's aspect, i believe it poofs.