# Who can earn fate points from invoking attached aspects?

Tags: fate-core

Fate Core (p. 81) states that you earn fate points when your aspects are invoked against you:

> If someone pays a fate point to invoke an aspect attached to your character, you gain their fate point at the end of the scene. This includes advantages created on your character, as well as consequences.

I mostly understand this rule, but I'm not sure which characters can benefit from it. Specifically:

- Which aspects count as “attached to your character”?
- Can the GM earn these fate points for the next scene?

Comment: Are you interested only in Official Rules answers, or would you welcome GM experience and houserule suggestions?

Comment: @BESW Both are great. Of course it's always good to know which stuff is official and which is personal advice.

Comment: In a [similar question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/what-happens-to-the-fate-point-after-a-character-invokes-an-aspect) for Dresden Files RPG, the answer refers to a rule on DFRPG p. 197 that characters get these fate points at the end of every _exchange_ in a conflict, instead of at the end of a scene. Is that rule also in Fate Core, or was it removed?

Comment: That would make an excellent *new* question, to which I have an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Which aspects count as “attached to your character”?

- Any aspect you wrote on the character sheet as part of character creation
- any aspect due to consequences of stress or concession of conflict.
- any aspect you have created upon yourself in play (usually by the create advantage action)
- any aspect inflicted upon you in play (usually by the create advantage action)

Aspects attached elsewhere are not normally attached to your character. For example, one could see this post as an attempt to create "Knows the rules" and attaching it to Bradd Szonye... If I succeed, Bradd has that aspect attached. I don't.

Likewise, if I create the aspect "Smelly Room," it attaches to the location, not to me. Someone else could invoke the location's aspect in attempting to affix to me the "Smells bad" aspect.

## Can the GM earn these fate points for the next scene?

No. See page 82 (emphasis mine):

> The NPCs under your
>   control are not so lucky.
>   They have a limited pool of
>   fate points you get to use
>   on their behalf. **Whenever
>   a scene starts, you get one
>   fate point for every PC
>   in that scene.** You can use
>   these points on behalf of
>   any NPC you want, but
>   you can get more in that
>   scene if they take a compel, like PCs do.
>
> **You reset to your default total, one per PC, at the beginning of every
>   scene.**
>
> There are two exceptions:
>
> - You accepted a compel that effectively ended the last scene or starts the
>     next one. If that happens, take an extra fate point in the next scene.
> - You conceded a conflict to the PCs in the previous scene. If that happens,
>     take the fate points you’d normally get for the concession into the
>     next scene and add them to the default total.
>
> If the immediate next scene doesn’t present a significant interaction with
>   NPCs, you can save these extra points until the next scene that does.

On a related but different "No"...
from page 81 (emphasis mine):

> Have Your Aspects Invoked Against You: If someone pays a fate point
>   to invoke an aspect attached to your character, **you gain their fate point
>   at the end of the scene.** This includes advantages created on your character,
>   as well as consequences.

This confirms that non-compel invokes do not grant fate to the NPC Fate Pool.

Comment: If I create the aspect, "Annoyingly convinced" and intend it to be compelled upon Bradd, it's attached to Bradd, not me... If I create the aspect "air filled with smoke from the Deacon's censor", it's able to be affixed to the deacon or to the location/zone, or to the scene as a whole. Once attached elsewhere, it's no longer mine. I don't get fate for it. But I get to use it, and so does everyone else. And yes, Scene A's points go away when A ends, and a new pool is created when Scene B begins; excepting, of course, scene ending concessions and/or accepted compels.

Comment: @aramis "No. See page 82 (emphasis mine):" - there's no emphasis!

Comment: @JonathanHobbs thanks - I revised from preview to released version, and forgot to re-emphasize.

Comment: Your third bullet ("any aspect you have created in play"): should that have another qualifier on it, like "on yourself"?

Comment: yes, it should.

Answer (score 6):

**Which aspects count as “attached to your character”?** This includes character aspects, consequences, and situation aspects attached to your character (p. 136), but not game aspects or situation aspects attached to the environment.

**Can the GM earn these fate points for the next scene?** The rules for GM fate points (p. 82) state that GMs take extra fate points for scene-ending compels and for conceding a conflict, but they don't mention aspects invoked against NPCs. Therefore, only players can earn fate points this way.

Comment: I think this is how the rules are supposed to work, but corrections and clarifications are welcome.